# Has there ever been a game-winning tip play off an inbounds pass in an NBA playoff game or NCAA Tournament game?

Tags: basketball, history, nba, collegiate, postseason

The NBA has the [Trent Tucker Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trent_Tucker_Rule), which states that if there is less than 0.3 seconds on the shot clock or game clock with a team inbounding the ball, then any player on that team cannot attempt to score by catching and shooting. Instead, they must attempt to score on a tip play. The NCAA has a similar rule, except that it is 0.4 seconds instead of 0.3 seconds.

There has been at least one game-winning tip play off an inbounds pass with less than 0.3 seconds left in a regular season NBA game. That occurred on December 21, 2006 when the Knicks beat the Bobcats on a [David Lee tip-in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q99sL_g3jvo) off an inbounds pass with 0.1 seconds left in the game.

Has there ever been a NBA playoff game with a game-winning tip off an inbounds pass (or a jump ball) with less than 0.3 seconds left? Or an NCAA Tournament game with a game-winning tip off an inbounds pass with less than 0.4 seconds left?

Answer (score 1):

In 1986 the league was not yet using tenths of a second, but I believe Ralph Sampson's shot at the end of regulation certainly fits the spirit of the question.  Inbounded with one second showing, Sampson makes a behind the head tip from twelve feet out to win the Western Conference Championship series.  The pertinent part of the video linked below begins at 9:24.